# Reading the output from a GLMM run in R

Tags: r, interpretation, glmm

I am a complete novice and dummy when it comes to statistics so I apologise in advance...

I have been asked to report the results of my GLMMs (I ran two) in a table. This table must state: effect, standard error, test statistic, and P value, for all fixed effects.

Unfortunately I am struggling to read my output.

The out put is as follows, if anyone would be kind enough to help I would be very grateful and will know for future reference which bit equates to what (also I have been told my degrees of freedom are different for both the tests, could someone explain why this is?).

```
GLMM 1-run for predictors of step length. 
Response variable = step length. 
fixed effects = depth and direction threshold. 
random factor = individual

Models:
m2: step ~ (1 | ind)
m1: step ~ Depth * threshold + (1 | ind)
Df AIC BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq) 
m2 3 373235 373259 -186615 373229 
m1 8 373225 373290 -186605 373209 19.767 5 0.001382 **
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

.

```
GLMM 2 -run to investigate potential predictors of PDBA.
response variables = depth and step length. 
fixed effect = direction threshold.
random factor = Individual

Models:
m3: PDBA ~ Depth + (1 | ind) + thresholdepth
m2: PDBA ~ step * threshold + Depth * threshold + (1 | ind)
Df AIC BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq) 
m3 6 -48205 -48157 24109 -48217 
m2 11 -48430 -48341 24226 -48452 235.1 5 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Models:
m4: PDBA ~ step + (1 | ind) + step:threshold
m2: PDBA ~ step * threshold + Depth * threshold + (1 | ind)
Df AIC BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq) 
m4 6 -48206 -48158 24109 -48218 
m2 11 -48430 -48341 24226 -48452 233.81 5 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Hi, I think the package I used was was lme4?

I have run a summary for the first GLMM and this is what I got, I have no idea which parts are relevant though, I assume it doesn't all go in a table?!

```
> summary(m1)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: step ~ Depth * threshold + (1 | ind) 

REML criterion at convergence: 373184 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ind      (Intercept) 196519   443.3   
 Residual             469370   685.1   
Number of obs: 23473, groups: ind, 11

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)      160.95895  134.80279   1.194
Depth              0.06438    0.44777   0.144
threshold2        51.18065   17.62222   2.904
threshold3         1.47733   21.43879   0.069
Depth:threshold2  -1.23654    0.60029  -2.060
Depth:threshold3  -0.09587    0.65088  -0.147

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Depth  thrsh2 thrsh3 Dpth:2
Depth       -0.094                            
threshold2  -0.090  0.712                     
threshold3  -0.075  0.588  0.567              
Dpth:thrsh2  0.071 -0.737 -0.745 -0.435       
Dpth:thrsh3  0.064 -0.674 -0.490 -0.857  0.502
```

For GLMM 1 I ran this code -

```
m1<-lmer(step~Depth*threshold+(1|ind))
m2<-lmer(step~(1|ind))
anova(m1,m2)
```

For GLMM 2 I ran this code -

```
m2<-lmer(PDBA~step*threshold+Depth*threshold+(1|ind))
m3<-update(m2,~.-step*threshold)
anova(m2,m3)
```

and this one:

```
m2<-lmer(PDBA~step*threshold+Depth*threshold+(1|ind))
m4<-update(m2,~.-Depth*threshold)
anova(m2,m4)
```

The output from the Anova only gives me one p value for each GLMM and I think I need a p value for each of the fixed effects within the models?

Does anyone know what code I can run to get this?
Thank you

Comment: can you say any more about what R packages/functions you actually used to get these results?

Comment: Hi Ben, I have just edited my query to include the package and the summary output of the first GLMM, thanks in advance if you can help me to understand the relevant bits!

Comment: The part that says `Fixed effects:` is what you want.  For p values, you probably want the `lmerTest` package.  See `?pvalues` in the `lme4` package.

Comment: Ok thanks Ben, I have that package, have you any idea what the code to find the p values would be? I have edited above to show the code I used to get the output so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "summary(model)" to get the information  (estimate, SE, p) for each fixed effect.